# Market Value of a publicly traded company

Tags: data-request, stock-market, financial-markets

I want to know the market value (market capitalization) of a company on a particular day in the recent past (within the past 5 years). How can I do this, may be with the help of Google Finance or Yahoo Finance or some other tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

If I type the search phrase `market capitalization msft 3rd December 2010` then the search engine returns the following:

[image]

If you use Wolfram Mathematica on your PC then you can import the data directly for processing using the `FinancialData` command (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html)).